# VMware Workstation. Virtual Machine copy/clone protection

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I will have to deploy a Virtual Machine on laptop. The user will can use this virtual machine with only one restriction, He can not copy/clone/move... this virtual machine to another computer.

If I encrypt the virtual machine the user will need the password to start the virtual machine... And He will can copy/move/clone... it.

I think that in the past VMware ACE did this operation but now I do not know how I can do it.

Do you know How Can I protect a VMware Virtual Machine to avoid the copy of this VM to another computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NTFS encrytion on Virtual Machine folder.

https://www.tomsguide.com/us/encrypt-files-windows,news-18314.html

After this, restrict user to write VMDK, OFV and other VMware files only in Virtual Machine folder

Comment: Hello Anderson, I tested your solution and works fine, but Could the user decrypt the folder and after that copy it?

Comment: Well, in this case I would suggest you to use a Third-Party application, such as Blok Free to restrict Windows Folder Settings.